# Почему вылезает ошибка LNK 2019 в программе с Magick++?

Tags: c++, imagemagick

код не работает,выдается ошибка LNK2019.Библиотеку Imagemagick подключил.В интернете решения не нашёл.Зарание спасибо за помощь!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int /*argc*/, char**/*argv*/){
// Create base image (white image of 300 by 200 pixels)
Image image(Geometry(300, 200), Color("white"));

// Set draw options
image.strokeColor("red"); // Outline color
image.fillColor("green"); // Fill color
image.strokeWidth(5);

// Draw a circle
image.draw(DrawableCircle(100, 100, 50, 100));

// Draw a rectangle
image.draw(DrawableRectangle(200, 200, 270, 170));

// Display the result
image.display();



return 0;
```

}

ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну и где текст ошибки?

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил

Comment: `Библиотеку Imagemagick подключил` означает, что вы указали в проекте библиотеку для link-а, а не `#include` в исходном тексте

Comment: @PavelGridin, ну заголовочный файл в коде явно есть.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну я это к тому, что народ обычно указав `#include` считает, что подключил библиотеку.

Comment: @PavelGridin, а, значит я не так фразу понял. Я почему-то подумал, что имеется в виду, что кроме подключения библиотеки надо написать include. А ты наоборот имел в виду)

Comment: проблема решена